# how to convert varchar to datetime ?in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

```
    SELECT  CONVERT(TIME,('5 h 0 m ')) AS HourMinuteSecond
            --CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),101) AS DateOnly
            GO
```

I am gettin an error while trying to make the convertion

```
  SELECT
CONVERT(TIME,('5 h 0 m ')) AS HourMinuteSecond
--CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),101) AS DateOnly
GO
```

Comment: That's not a valid time format. It's definitely not a datetime. What are you trying to do? Why use *that* format in the database instead of an actual `time` value or the universal `05:00` format?

Comment: `select cast('5:00' as time)`

Comment: The question (I use that word loosely, as you don't actually ask a question in your question) is conflicting. Your title says `datetime` but your query says `time`. What are you trying to achieve here? What value are you expecting? What other values would we be expecting? it looks like you aren't using leading 0's, which is (probably) going to be a problem. Add more sample data, and add expected results.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If that string comes from a client, the client should be fixed so it uses `time`-typed parameters or at least a valid time string. If that string comes from a file, it should be cleaned up as part of the ETL job.

Answer (score 0):

Format you are using is not valid, but still if you want to convert the string as time, you can try like following.

```
SELECT CONVERT(TIME,REPLACE(REPLACE(RTRIM('5 h 0 m '),' h ',':'),'m','')) 
AS HourMinuteSecond
```